# Downgrade GNU make version from 4.1 to 3.81 or 3.82

Tags: gnu-make, gnu

Could anyone please let me know how to downgrade GNU package. I tried to download make-3.82.tar.gz file and extracted it and ran .configure. Then tried to run make got below error,

/glob/glob.c:577 undefined reference to '__alloca'
glob/libglob.a(glob.o):/path/glob/glob.c:728 more undefined reference to '__alloca' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.
Makefile: 359: recipe for target 'make' failed.

Thanks

Comment: Without the context of which system you are using, this is a hard question.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 version

Comment: Just uninstall and install the older one.

Comment: Tried it, but not able to do so. got above mentioned error.

Comment: It would be better if we have any link to refer. @Rob

Comment: This looks like a XY-problem. I doubt that 3.82 will link differently than 4.2. What could we do to help you correcting your build without downgrading nearly twenty (!) years?